# cout prints memory address instead of value

Tags: c++

I saw another question basically the same as this, however it included pointers and I have no pointers in my code.
I am trying to practice using classes, specifically the access modifiers.
I have created a class in a header file called Bankaccount. When I try to print out the private variable "balance," it prints out what I believe to be an address because it's a bunch of random numbers, however there is no letter in it like most hex addresses I've seen. I am not quite sure why this is happening.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studios 2019. I have included all of the code below (both the source file and the header file).
If anyone can let me know why it is printing the address of the variable "balance" then please let me know.
Also, any constructive criticism you would like to add about any of my code (since I am a beginner), please add.
Thank you so much.

Header File

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bankaccount {
public:
    Bankaccount() {
        int choice;
        cout << "Constructor run properly." << endl;
        cout << "You have created a bank account." << endl;
        cout << "What will the name of the account be?   Name: ";
        cin >> accoutName;
        cout << "What would you like to do with this account?\nDeposit: Press 1" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1) {
            int depo;
            cout << "Deposit amount: ";
            cin >> depo;
            deposit(depo);
            cout << "$" << depo << " dollars has been added to your account." << endl;
        }

    }
    int deposit(int deposit) {
        balance += deposit;
        return balance;
    }
    void getBalance() {
        cout << "your balance is: " << balance << endl;
    }
    ~Bankaccount() {
        cout << "Destructor run properly." << endl;
    }

private:
    string accoutName;
    int balance;
};
```

Source File

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bank.h"

int main() {
    Bankaccount Joseph;
    Joseph.getBalance();
}
```

Comment: Hint -- That is not a memory address that is being printed out, it is a random value.

Comment: Hint 2 -- there's smth wrong with the *initialization* of the `balance` variable.

Comment: The constructor should give `balance` an initial value.

Comment: Also, the `Bankaccount` constructor shouldn't really have input routines embedded in it.  What if someone wants to create a `Bankaccount` with already known data?

Comment: The fewer assumptions you make about the cause of your error, the less likely you are to go barking up the wrong tree. Focus your questions on what was observed, and relegate speculation to (at most) an ending note. (Also, it might be useful to [explain why you believe your code should work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).)

Comment: Thanks you guys, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, I have the cin statements in the constructor because I was picturing this as if someone was starting an account from scratch. I am not at all going to embellish this code because I am just practicing using classes.

Comment: *I was picturing this as if someone was starting an account from scratch.* -- Then you could have just `cin` all of the data from outside the class, and then just construct a `Bankaccount` with an `accountName` and deposit as arguments.  That would have probably *easier* than what you have now, not more embellished.

Comment: Wait, so is having input routines inside of class constructors like a "taboo" of some sort in programming?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a memory address being printed for `balance`.  It is the output of an uninitialized variable.

The issue is that `balance` is uninitialized when creating `Bankaccount` objects.  You should initialize `balance` when constructing `Bankaccount` objects:

```
class Bankaccount 
{
   int balance;
   public:
       Bankaccount() : balance(0) { 
       // ...
       }
};
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I was just reading about the member initializer list XD. Thank you so much for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Bankaccount Joseph;` a `Bankaccount` object is allocated space on the stack (here, it means that space is allocated for it's members `balance` and `accoutName`). When an object is constructed it's the constructor's responsibility to initialise all members to have the right initial value. For example, when a `Bankaccount` is created setting the `balance` to be `0`. If this is not done, just the memory is claimed but not initialised (it may contain some junk values - possibly from the previous functions that happened to used this space).

In your code `balance` is not set to `0` - it has some junk instead. When the user inputs a new `deposit` amount, it is added to this junk and produces a value as a result that also looks like a junk value. You can do this the first thing you enter the constructor.

```
Bankaccount() {
    deposit = 0;
```

(Please note: `accountName` of type `string` is not a primitive data type, it's constructed elsewhere, and its constructor will make sure that it holds an empty string `""` to begin with. It is just wrapping a managed array of `char`s.)

Comment: I am going to be honest, I laughed when I read the second part of your response. You explained that very well, thank you.